# How to temporary disable XSS Auditor in chrome v68 on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, xss

I'm developing XSS vulnerable system with php in ubuntu 18.04 but i can not figure it out how to close XSS Auditor in Chrome v68 temporarily. Also i tried to do in Firefox but it response 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

guys i don't change chrome settings but i add this script to my code and it works.

```
<?php header("X-XSS-Protection: 0; mode=block"); ?>
```

This code part helps to change HTTP Response header.